# Compute the expectation of $\log|X|$ if $X$ is uniformly distributed on the unit ball.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, uniform-distribution

I am working on an exercise which requires me to compute $\mathbb{E}\log|X|$, where $X$ is uniformly distributed on the unit ball $\{u\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:|u|\leq 1\}$.

I know that this uniform distribution implies that $$\mathbb{P}(|X|\leq r)=r^{2}\ \text{for}\ 0\leq r\leq 1\ \ (*),$$ then I tried to use the formula $$\mathbb{E}|X|^{p}=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(|X|>x)dx,$$ to compute $$\mathbb{E}\log|X|=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\log|X|>x)dx,$$ what should I do next to use $(*)$?

Thank you!

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\int \mathbb{P}(Y\geq y)dy$ only for *non-negative* RVs, which $Y=\log |X|$ is definitely not since $|X| \leq 1$ a.s. Right?

Comment: Oh yes you are right.. I thought about this in an opposite way. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use that formula, you need to notice that $\log|X| \leq 0$ so instead you would write

$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}\log|X| &= -\mathbb{E}[-\log|X|] \\&= -\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(-\log|X| > x)\,dx \\&= -\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X| < e^{-x})\,dx\end{align*}$$

Now note that $0 < x < \infty \implies 0 < e^{-x} < 1$ so you can use $(*)$ directly.

Comment: Thank you so much!